# How to remove a play store error "unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier"

Tags: android, paytm

I am getting the following error,

> Security alert Your app is using an **unsafe implementation of
> HostnameVerifier**.
>
> Please see this Google Help Center article for
> details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.
> Vulnerable classes: **com.paytm.pgsdk.i** Affects APK version 10.

while uploading my app on google play. My app has paytm integrated with Paytm sdk.

Please help me with any solution or suggestion how to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to remove the error "unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier".

> Simply use in **https URLs** in both the **PaytmMerchant URLs**
>   (inChecksumGenerationURL and inChecksumVerificationURL).

Comment: Gupta what if we are generating and verifying checksum server side?

Comment: @JaykishanSewak yeah agreed with you, there must be some solution for that too. Because this is a very old post. And technologies change day by day.